# How to get input from an EditText field in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

When coding for Android, there are two main ways I have seen to get text from an editText field. The first way seems to be very commonly used, and looks a little like this.

```
display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
displayContents = display.getText().toString();
displayTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
displayText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
displayText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        displayTwo.setText(displayContents);
    }
```

This seems to use a clickListener in the mainActivity class to detect the click, then finds the value of the textfields.

However, when I was looking through [Google's official Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), they used an alternative method. They first added this line of code to the button:

```
android:onClick="sendMessage";
```

and then had this method instead of the onClickListener:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

After that, i created a new activity which made a new xml file with a different GUI, and a new class with the following:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Get the message from the intent
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

// Create the text view
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);

// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);
}
```

This seems to have the button broadcast a message rather than having a passive listener, and then trigger a new activity.

So after all that, I suppose my question would be which method is better to use? From both a technical and design standpoint, which one works with what situations? Like, when would I use each one?

Comment: First of all, what you're probably speaking about is how to attach a click listener to a certain View, and therefore the title of your question is confusing. Second, the questions you ask in the second part of the post should be divided in a number of separate SO questions. At the moment, your question is too broad and vague

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm still new to Stack Exchange. I'll edit my question to only include the first one. What do you think I should change my title to, by the way, because I'm not really sure about the things I'm getting into here. Also, if I wanted a more in-depth explanation of Intents, can I ask here? I'm just wondering because I don't really get it and I wanted a more human answer to explain things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty new to android so I could be wrong, but pretty sure they are the same thing. When you add `android:onClick="sendMessage";`
it go's through the same type of listener, you just don't have to actually personally program that in yourself.

Which to use is arguably a personal preference I guess. Personally if things are easy such as click this to open an intent then I would use

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
```

But if I wanted the listener to parse variables through, or utilise variables within a specific method I guess, then it would be easier for me to create my own listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the two methods mentioned above. There is no any technical difference in both of them.
And to learn about those thing go to this link af android developers

http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

Answer (score 0):

the second method in which the intent is used to pass the string to another activity is used only when you need to pass the string to a new activity.
if you have both of your edittexts in the same activity xml then go with the button clicklistener.
now to do something on button click we have to methods

1. with java listener
2. with xml onclick attribute

these methods will do the same thing , either one can be used.

you can create new activity using intent in java listener also with the same code.